# How to load main screen while on splash screen?

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I am developing an android app using monodroid, anyway i have noticed that monodroid apps take longer to stratup so I decided to implement a splash screen. Right now I have implemented the splash screen using monodroid tutorials, but when I open the app it still shows a black screen before loading the splash so I decided to implement a java splash screen which I have noticed loads without the black screen.

Anyway I have the java splash screen implemented but the problem is that now the main activity starts after the splash screen timeout is over, so the splash finishes and it displays the black screen for a few seconds and then shows the main activity.

Is there anyway to load the mainactivity in background while the splash screen is being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Use Background Threads like Async Task.

Refer to the link

http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/

Comment: how can I implement this to load my main screen while showing the splash screen? and also how could I report that the main menu UI is already loaded to stop the splash screen?